# Is there a kotlin way of restricting toString() override for class with delegated properties

Tags: kotlin, delegates

I am new to Kotlin and i was trying out the exapmles in documentation for custom delegated properties.

https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Delegated%20properties/Custom%20delegate/Custom%20delegate.kt

usually when overriding the toString method,i restrict the fields which i want to print as in the code provided.

In this  case ,p is delagated property where we use thisref in getValue() string .
So here it creates a problem of stackoverflow due to recursive calls.

```
class Example {
    var p: String by Delegate()
    var q: String = "testQ"

    override fun toString() = "Example[p=$p]"
}

class Delegate() {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>): String {
        return "$thisRef, thank you for delegating '${prop.name}' to me!"
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, prop: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
        println("$value has been assigned to ${prop.name} in $thisRef")
    }
}
```

As delegated properties are inteneded for a common library,is there any restrictions on the toString() override method we should follow .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the delegate, but with the recursion:

1. Example.toString() is called
2. Delegate.getValue() is called by `$p`. An instance of Example is passed to getValue.
3. Example.toString() is called by `$thisRef`. So it loops back to step 1!!

You can reproduce the same with this very simple example:

```
fun main() {
    class SimpleExample {
        override fun toString() = "$this"
    }

    println(SimpleExample())
}
```

In order to fix it, remove the `$thisRef` from the `getValue` function.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the response. but i wanted to know if there is a way to find this issue at compile time rather than at runtime.

Comment: I don't think so. You can try to write annotation processor looking for never-ending recursion. Or maybe a static code analyser would do the job.

Comment: @Dinesh please update your question and make it clear then

Comment: @Gustavo..i have updated the subject.I think it should be clear now.

Comment: I was just curious in case the library and class are created by different person.there could be a chance for an issue (may be very less chanec).

Answer (score 1):

```
return "$thisRef ... "
```

In line above you want to invoke `thisRef.toString()` (in string templates `toString` is implicitly called). And that tries to execute following line: `"Example[p=$p]"`. So, it try to invoke `thisRef.toString()` again, and we are again in `"Example[p=$p]"` call.

It would say that is totally expected behavior. What you can do then? In your case just remove `thisRef.toString` call from your delegate method.